# How to sort data by hierarchy

Tags: sorting, ampersand

Lets say I have some data like this

```
Name        | ID  | ParentID | Level
------------+-----+----------+-------
Fruits      | 1   | 0        | 1
Vegetables  | 2   | 0        | 1
  Apple     | 3   | 1        | 2
  Banana!!  | 4   | 1        | 2
  Tomato    | 5   | 2        | 2
  Potato    | 6   | 2        | 2
    red     | 7   | 5        | 3
    green   | 8   | 5        | 3
```

How to sort (compare) this data to get a result like this:

```
Name        | ID  | ParentID | Level
------------+-----+----------+---------
Fruits      | 1   | 0        | 1
  Apple     | 3   | 1        | 2
  Banana!!  | 4   | 1        | 2
Vegetables  | 2   | 0        | 1
  Tomato    | 5   | 2        | 2
    red     | 7   | 5        | 3
    green   | 8   | 5        | 3
  Potato    | 6   | 2        | 2
```

Background is that I have a model-collection with models and I want to add them according to the hierarchy given by ID/ParentID